# Display inline model in the details page of the parent model? Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I have a model A, which incorporates an inline model B that allows users to enter some texts. Currently, the data users added into the inline model can only be shown in the 'edit' page of the parent model A, but not in the 'details' page. Is there a way to solve this?

edit-page

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the field in model B to the `column_details_list` ([docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_details_list))

Add the same field in model B to the `column_formatters_detail` dictionary ([docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_formatters_detail)), specifying a formatter method that returns appropriate HTML.

For example:

```
from markupsafe import Markup

class ExampleView(AdminView):

    # include the comments child field plus any parent fields from model A you want to show
    column_details_list =  ('name', 'last_name', 'comments')    

    def _comments_formatter(view, context, model, name):
        # model is parent model A
        _html = []
        if model.comments:
            #  return any valid HTML markup
            for _comment_model in model.comments:
                # add html para per comment
                _html.append(f'<p>User:{str(_comment_model.user)}, Comment:{_comment_model.comment}</p>')

            return Markup(''.join(_html))

    column_formatters_detail = {
        'comments': _comments_formatter
    }
```